# Hadoop: Pig error

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2

I am an absolute beginner in Hadoop, and I am only doing some simple testing, however, I do not find error messages very informative.

I have set up my Hadoop environment in a single-node mode on a CentOS 6.4 VM with 4Gb of RAM available.

I am trying to run a simple Pig script over a 500Mb CSV file. I have two 500Mb files, on the first one, the script was successful. On the second one, which is about the same size, but different data (a lot more rows), I get an error when the execution reaches about 60%.

This is the (very simple) Pig script I use:

```
records = LOAD 'trans2013.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS
(podracun_v_breme,datum_transakcije,znesek_transakcije,oznaka_valute_transakcije,racun_v_dobro,naziv_prejemnika,maticna_stevilka,davcna_stevilka,sifra_pu,zr_sns_oe,namen);
transaction_recs = GROUP records ALL;
tot_trans = FOREACH transaction_recs GENERATE
SUM(records.znesek_transakcije);
STORE tot_trans INTO '/user/root/totaltransactions';
```

This is the error I get in the terminal:

> 2014-04-06 10:28:29,147 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - 64% complete 2014-04-06 10:28:30,240 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure. 2014-04-06 10:28:30,241 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - job job_1396637732046_0008 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs 2014-04-06 10:28:30,241 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - 100% complete 2014-04-06 10:28:30,460 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - ERROR 2997: Unable to
>   recreate exception from backed error:
>   AttemptID:attempt_1396637732046_0008_m_000001_0 Info:Container killed
>   by the ApplicationMaster.
>
> 2014-04-06 10:28:30,461 [main] ERROR
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s)
>   failed! 2014-04-06 10:28:30,463 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics:
>
> HadoopVersion PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
>   2.0.6-alpha   0.11.1  root    2014-04-06 10:25:49 2014-04-06 10:28:30 GROUP_BY
>
> Failed!
>
> Failed Jobs: JobId    Alias   Feature Message Outputs
>   job_1396637732046_0008    records,tot_trans,transaction_recs  GROUP_BY,COMBINER   Message:
>   Job failed!   /user/root/totaltransactions,
>
> Input(s): Failed to read data from
>   "hdfs://localhost:8020/user/root/trans2013.csv"
>
> Output(s): Failed to produce result in "/user/root/totaltransactions"
>
> Counters: Total records written : 0 Total bytes written : 0 Spillable
>   Memory Manager spill count : 0 Total bags proactively spilled: 0 Total
>   records proactively spilled: 0
>
> Job DAG: job_1396637732046_0008
>
> 2014-04-06 10:28:30,463 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - Failed! 2014-04-06 10:28:30,491 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser - ERROR 2997: Unable to
>   recreate exception from backed error:
>   AttemptID:attempt_1396637732046_0008_m_000001_0 Info:Container killed
>   by the ApplicationMaster.
>
> Details at logfile: /root/pig_1396797945352.log

Here is the error from the log:

> Backend error message
>   --------------------- AttemptID:attempt_1396637732046_0008_m_000001_0 Info:Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
>
> Pig Stack Trace
>   --------------- ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: AttemptID:attempt_1396637732046_0008_m_000001_0 Info:Container
>   killed by the ApplicationMaster.
>
> org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2997:
>   Unable to recreate exception from backed error:
>   AttemptID:attempt_1396637732046_0008_m_000001_0 Info:Container killed
>   by the ApplicationMaster.
>
> at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.Launcher.getErrorMessages(Launcher.java:217)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.Launcher.getStats(Launcher.java:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:400)
>     at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1264)     at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1249)
>     at org.apache.pig.PigServer.execute(PigServer.java:1239)    at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:333)     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:170)
>     at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)     at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:604)    at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:157)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So ... I tried running Pig script with mapreduce option:

```
pig -x mapreduce script.pig
```

It still failed, but it at least produced a meaningful error. It seems I had to remove the header from the CSV file, because Pig used the header row as data. It seems this only happens when working with floating point numbers - if using the same script with integers, the header row would simply be ignored.

So that was it. First removed the header from the file, than running the script against it - it worked.